# Angular Material setValidity message does not animate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular material and am trying to accomplish validating a form using server-side validation. The fields are sent to my php framework, validated and if there are errors the application responds with a JSON of error messages associated with input fields. I then accomplish displaying errors to the user using:

```
$scope.errormessage = response.message;
$scope.myform.myinput.$setValidity('errormessage', false);
```

This works but the message is not being animated - it appears instantly. If I use ng-required the message is animated. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or if there is some other way to approach this problem?

Angular material demo for messages is located here:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

Thank you.